# How to pivot a table using specific columns in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pivot, data-science, pivot-table

My DataFrame looks something like this

```
df=pd.DataFrame("Country":["India","China","USA","UK"]
                     2001:[11,12,13,14]
                     2002:[21,22,23,24]
                     2003:[31,32,33,34]
                     2004:[41,42,43,44]
```

How can I pivot it in such a way that my DataFrame look something like below:

```
df=pd.DataFrame("Country":["India","India","India","India","China","China","China","China","USA","USA","USA","USA","UK","UK","UK","UK"]
                   "Year":[2001,2002,2003,2004,2001,2002,2003,2004,2001,2002,2003,2004,2001,2002,2003,2004,2001,2002,2003,2004]
                  "Value":[11,21,31,41,12,22,32,42,13,23,33,43,14,24,34,44]
```

Comment: Can you provide correct input and output data please?

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
>>> (df.set_index('Country').rename_axis(columns='Year')
       .stack().rename('Value').reset_index())
   Country  Year  Value
0    India  2001     11
1    India  2002     21
2    India  2003     31
3    India  2004     41
4    China  2001     12
5    China  2002     22
6    China  2003     32
7    China  2004     42
8      USA  2001     13
9      USA  2002     23
10     USA  2003     33
11     USA  2004     43
12      UK  2001     14
13      UK  2002     24
14      UK  2003     34
15      UK  2004     44
```

You can also use `melt`:

```
>>> df.melt('Country', var_name='Year', value_name='Value')
   Country  Year  Value
0    India  2001     11
1    China  2001     12
2      USA  2001     13
3       UK  2001     14
4    India  2002     21
5    China  2002     22
6      USA  2002     23
7       UK  2002     24
8    India  2003     31
9    China  2003     32
10     USA  2003     33
11      UK  2003     34
12   India  2004     41
13   China  2004     42
14     USA  2004     43
15      UK  2004     44
```